# From running application detect another try w/ params

Tags: shell, process, vb6

Is it possible that my running application written in VB6 detects another command to run. (sorry: English).

Basically:
- I write an APP in VB6
- I start it. 
- I try to run the same application again with some parameters
- My app should now detect that I tried to run it again and read above parameters

Is it possible? - Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to detect and close the previously opened app?

Comment: No, but it looks like it is not possible. What I wanted was to have already running application detects same copy of application that is being initialized ... I found another way around and sorted everything out. Thanks